# Modificar word con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este código pero no funciona.

Me crea el nuevo archivo pero no me modifica la palabra. He probado a hacer lo mismo con un archivo con la extensión `.txt` y sí funciona, pero con el archivo de **Word** no lo consigo.

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

$archivo = 'textito.docx'; // Ruta al archivo de Word

$palabraAntigua = 'nombre';
$nuevaPalabra = 'Manolooo';

$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($archivo);

$templateProcessor->setValue($palabraAntigua, $nuevaPalabra);

$archivoModificado = 'Document2.docx'; // Ruta al nuevo archivo de Word
$templateProcessor->saveAs($archivoModificado);

echo "La palabra '$palabraAntigua' ha sido reemplazada por '$nuevaPalabra' y se ha guardado en el archivo '$archivoModificado'.";
```

Comment: Hola Otto, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo del contenido en el archivo `textito.docx`?

Comment: Considera meter tu código dentro de un bloque `try ... catch` para controlar eventuales errores. Haciendo eso, dinos qué error muestra o bien revisa el log de errores.

Comment: Solucionado! parte del error estaba en el archivo word, la palabra que quieras cambiar debe estar así: ${hola} y no lo sabía